# jQuery not "takes" the content inside the container in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a div like this:

```
<div class='x' data-x='xxx'>

<div> bla bla </div>
<a> blabla </a>
<!-- other stuff -->

</div>
```

Then with jquery I do this:

```
var divs= $('#wrapper .x');
$('#wrapper').html('');
```

(I need to take the formatted divs and use them later, so I create them with php and remove them with JS to use later)

If I log the var divs[0] whit chrome all right, i see the whole div (container + content):

```
<div class='x' data-x='xxx'>

<div> bla bla </div>
<a> blabla </a>
<!-- other stuff -->

</div>
```

But if I log that in IE (using IE 11) I get ONLY the container:

```
<div class='x' data-x='xxx'></div>
```

Why this? How can i fix this?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

It seems unbelievable, although I store the divs in a VAR, if I don't clone them with $().clone() they loose the content in IE... and that's not logical because I'm not storing a ref to a collection, but I'm storing the collection itself...

Another thing, it seems to "see" what should happen later and change the behavior:

```
var divs= $('#wrapper .x');
console.log(divs[0]); //WORK

var divs= $('#wrapper .x');
console.log(divs[0]); //NOT WORK <-- why?!
$('#wrapper').html(''); <-- this should execute later!

var divs= $('#wrapper .x').clone();
console.log(divs[0]); //WORK
$('#wrapper').html('');
```

(That's not the real code, it is more complex and I have posted the "logical" function)

Comment: You're actually removing the div elements there. They are not in the DOM anymore. My poorly guess is that it is browser's decision afterwords what to do with them.. Chrome may cache them, but maybe others don't..

Comment: @Noldor I updated the post

Comment: @Noldor Generally, DOM nodes should use the same reference-counting the rest of the garbage collector uses. The DOM itself is one reference, but even a var should count as a reference to keep it.

Comment: @Katana314 OP only has a `var` reference to the div, not to all of the nodes inside it.

Comment: @JLRishe Indirect references are still references, arguably. I suppose it's down to just which references a browser decides are "weak" and should not maintain an element's existence. (For instance, if two neighbors are removed, nextChild/previousChild shouldn't cause them to keep existing)

Comment: @Katana314 Ok, but there's no evidence that OP's issue has anything to do with garbage collection anyway (if the child nodes of OP's DIVs were being garbage collected while they were still attached, OP would wind up having a DIV with broken references). It seems like IE is just traversing down and detaching elements. That's the kind of thing that can happen with mutable objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're setting an element's inner HTML to empty, what happens to the contents of that element is anyone's guess. If the browser wants to recursively traverse down and delete nodes, that's what it's going to do.

If you want to preserve some nodes you've selected before you empty their parent, you can detach them from the DOM ahead of time with `.remove()`:

```js
var divs = $('#wrapper .x');
divs.remove();                 // <--- here
$('#wrapper').html('');
console.log(divs[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class='x' data-x='xxx'>

    <div>bla bla</div>
    <a> blabla </a>
    <!-- other stuff -->

  </div>
</div>
```

As for why this is not working like you expect:

```
var divs= $('#wrapper .x');
console.log(divs[0]); //NOT WORK <-- why?!
$('#wrapper').html(''); <-- this should execute later
```

you can't trust `console.log()` to always show the value of an object at the moment it executes. If the value of that object changes after `console.log()` runs, the console can very well change to show the new value.

Comment: *"after console.log() runs"* or even before you choose to expand it in the console, but after the console.log runs in the case of objects. The only way to prevent that would be to log a specific value rather than an object.

Comment: So a jquery object does not contain the DOM element selected but instead a reference to it?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug, or at least a difference, with IE11's version of the `.innerHTML` property. It's maintaining references to nodes you can still reference, but not their children nodes.

You could get around this by replacing lines of this kind:

```
$('#wrapper').html('');
//with:
$('#wrapper > *').remove();
```

This appeared to keep the text when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug of IE's implementation of `innerHTML`.

To remove element's contents while maintaining corresponding nodes and their contents, use native `textContent = ''` or jQuery's `text('')`.

Comment: I think this will remove the text content that he wants, while leaving the `<div>`s behind.

Comment: @Katana314 `element.textContent = ''` removes all contents of the `element`, while contained nodes and their text contents are _not_ destroyed (if there are previously saved references to them) unlike `innerHTML`.

Comment: Do you have a source to back up your statement that this is a bug? Is there some spec outlining what should happen to the old contents of an element when a value is assigned to its `innerHTML`?

Comment: @JLRishe I have my own experience. This is a bug of IE's implementation of `innerHTML` as well as IE's nonstandard `innerText`. Other browsers including the new Microsoft Edge browser do not have this bug. I didn't report the bug myself and not aware of an existing bug-tracker ticket. Moreover, given that it's unlikely that there will be any new major versions of IE (IE11 seems to be our new IE6 until it's removed from Windows completely in favor of Edge), the bug is unlikely to be ever fixed even if reported.